# Getting a value from jquery mobile slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, firebase

This is driving me crazy. I'm working with jquery mobile 1.4.5 and firebase and I have this code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>

            <label for="size">Stroke thickness:</label>
            <input type="range" name="size" id="size" value="5" min="1" max="100" data-highlight="true">

        </div>

        <script>

            //Keeps updated with the current size in firebase
            currentSize.on("value", function(snapshot)
            {
                siz = snapshot.val();
                $("#size").val(siz);
                $("#size").slider("refresh");
            });

            $("#size").on('slidestop', function(event)
            {
                var a = $("#size").val();
                currentSize.set(a);
            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I update the value of the slider from firebase. This works fine.

The problem is when I try to set it. It simply doesn't work and I've tried many ways, unless I put the **data-role="none"** attribute, then it works like a charm, but of course without the nice mobile theme.

I'll really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried out [slide-stop](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/forms/slider/events.html)? I'm not sure why this would be failing, but that may shed some light. Seems like there's more to tinker with here. Also, can you make your code valid? I doubt you have random javaScript on an undefined `currentSize` variable dropped into your HTML without any `<script>` tags. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried that with the same negative results.
Sorry for the formatting...